Game with an unfair coin

You and your friend are playing a game with an unfair coin that lands on heads 2/3​ of the time. Each of you chooses a different two-coin sequence (HT, TH, HH, TT). The coin is then tossed repeatedly until one of the sequences appears, declaring that player the winner. You get to choose your sequence first, and then your friend picks a different one. Would you want to play this game? What is the probability that you will win?

I believe going as the first player would be disadvantageous as the second player could counter whatever sequence I choose with a sequence of higher probability of winning. I don't know how to rigorously prove this and find the probability.
Can someone help me with this question? Thanks!

Wouldn't just choosing HH be the most advantageous since it has the highest probability of appearing out of the four possible sequences?

@CosmicOscillator:  No, If you pick that I pick TH and win $5/9$ of the time.  You only win when the first two flips are HH.

@RossMillikan so going as the second player would be advantageous right? Is there a rigorous proof for this quesion?

This is a biased version of Penney's game.  The unbiased version requires three-coin sequences to get the same counter-intuitive results.

@CosmicOscillator HH is indeed the most advantageous choice for player 1 (anything else gives player 2 an even better counter). But it's still better to be player 2.

You are right! Perhaps unintuitively, it is actually better to go second. We can prove this by showing every possible two coin sequence has a counter, like you said, with a higher probability of coming first.
1. If Player 1 chooses TT, Player 2 will choose TH. After the first tails is rolled, a heads is by definition more likely than a tails to come next. So TH has a higher probability of occurring before TT.
2. If Player 1 chooses TH, Player 2 will choose HT. If the first roll is T, then TH will always come before HT no matter what. Likewise, if the first roll is H, then HT will always come before TH no matter what. So again, a heads is more likely to be rolled first and hence HT has a higher probability of occurring before TH.
3. If Player 1 chooses HT, Player 2 will choose HH. Like Case 1, after the first heads is rolled, heads next is more likely than tails. So HH has a higher probability of occurring than HT.
4. If Player 1 chooses HH, Player 2 will choose TH. Note that HH will come before TH if and only if the first two rolls are HH. This has probability $(2/3)^2 = 4/9$, meaning TH has a $5/9$ probability of coming before HH.
I summarize the above in the following table: $$
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Player 1's Choice}}
& \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Player 2's Counter}}\\\hline
 \text{TT} & \text{TH} \\\hline
 \text{TH} & \text{HT} \\\hline
 \text{HT} & \text{HH} \\\hline
 \text{HH} & \text{TH} 
\end{array}
$$
But wait, if we let $F(\text{xx})$ be the frequency of xx occurring, or the probability that xx comes first out of the four possible sequences, or something along those lines, doesn't this mean $$F(\text{TH}) < F(\text{HT}) < F(\text{HH}) < F(\text{TH})?$$ Why isn't there a dominant strategy (like HH) which beats everything else?
It is true that HH has the highest probability of occurring in the first two flips, and it is true that, asymptotically, HH has the highest frequency. But that's the thing - this question isn't asking about the first two rolls, or about asymptotic behaviour. It simply asks which of two sequences occur first.
All I've said is that $$P(\text{TT occurs before TH occurs}) < P(\text{TH occurs before TT occurs}),$$ and $$P(\text{TH occurs before HT occurs}) < P(\text{HT occurs before TH occurs}),$$ and so on. We can't chain the inequalities to create a contradiction like I did above, since each probability term refers to two 2-coin sequences, not one; That is, since $P$(TH occurs before TT occurs) is a different thing to $P$(TH occurs before HT occurs).

+1.  With $P(H)=\frac23$, HH also has the lowest expected of number of tosses needed to first appear (HH $\frac{15}{4}$ tosses, HT $\frac{18}4$, TH  $\frac{18}4$, TT $\frac{48}4$).  But with $P(H)=\frac35$ this would no longer be the case  (HH $\frac{160}{36}$ tosses, HT $\frac{150}{36}$, TH $\frac{150}{36}$, TT $\frac{315}{36}$).

If player 1 picked TT, wouldn't it be better for player 2 to pick HT (8/9 probability of winning) rather than TH (2/3 probability of winning)?

@Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica yes, but it doesn't change my argument

"Perhaps unintuitively" <<< Intuitively, picking first is good in a game that has a best combination, and bad in a game that has rock-paper-scissor-like combinations.
